# Apache mod_rewrite: can these simple RewriteRule be improved? And suggestions!

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I started finally to understand Apache mod_rewrite. It's pretty GREAT!

Plz have a look at the followings:

---

1) Permanent redirects `http://www.domain.com/folder_name/` (with or without final slash and with or without the `www`) to `http://www.domain.com/some/path/some_page.html`

```
RewriteRule ^folder_name[/]*$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/some\/path\/some_page.html" [R=301,L]
```

---

2) Permanent redirects all requests to `www.domain.com...` to same path and file request but without `www` in domain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

---

**They all work as expected and do their jobs**, I'm simply curios if some guy, who is more expert than me in mod_rewrite, could give me some advises like: "it could be better in this way...", "there might be a problem if...", etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the `?` quantifier instead of `*` and you don’t need to escape the substitution URL:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^folder_name/?$ http://example.com/some/path/some_page.html [R=301,L]
   ```
2. You might want to consider HTTP 1.0 requests where the *Host* header field is missing. Another useful extension would be to take HTTPS into account:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(|example\.com)$
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on(s)|
   RewriteRule ^ http%1://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   ```